# Simple RewriteRule with nginx

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, nginx

I'm trying to write a RewriteRule to make a simple url. I want users to be able to type enter

```
www.example.com/somepage
```

and have it take them to

```
www.example.com/abc/somepage.php
```

How can this be done in .htaccess?

I've tried these to no avail:

```
RewriteRule ^somepage$ abc/somepage.php [L]

RewriteRule ^/somepage$ /abc/somepage.php [L]
```

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** nginx can also handle rewrites in its configuration files (and I think is actually preferred), which was my case (see my answer below). HTH

Comment: Are you really trying to use .htaccess with **nginx**, or should that tag be **apache**? http://wiki.nginx.org/LikeApache-htaccess

Comment: We are using the Magento framework, which uses .htaccess by default I believe.

Comment: The request might have a trailing slash. You may try `RewriteRule ^somepage/?$ /abc/somepage.php` instead. If still doesn't work, where is the .htaccess file and what are the options, if any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the user's web browser to be redirected to your PHP page then you need the `R=301` flag at the end of the RewriteRule.

But if you want the request to be silently rewritten (so that Apache knows where to find the resource, but the user's web browser just sees the "clean" URL) then you don't want the `R' flag.

Try the following:

```
RewriteRule ^somepage$ /abc/somepage.php
```

This will only rewrite a request for /somepage so that Apache fetches the content from /abc/somepage.php instead.

Comment: Thanks for the info, however I only want it to specifically be `somepage`

Comment: The rewrites were being done in the .conf files, which I think caused the rewrites in .htaccess to be ignored. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Our nginx server was utilizing .htaccess files (as I implemented rewrites there before), but now it is handling the rewrites in its configuration (.conf) files (which is the recommended method).

I do not have permission to modify the .conf files, so I won't post any untested code.. Hope this helps somebody!

Comment: Do you have a reference for the assertion that `nginx can utilize .htaccess files much like Apache`? In everything I've seen, the nginx devs refuse to support .htaccess because (they believe, and I don't disagree) it is a terrible mechanism for server configuration.

Comment: No, I do not. I rephrased my answer. I don't disagree either.